# Shorting two pins of SoC in device tree standard (dts file)

Tags: embedded-linux, device-tree

I want to connect to pins in my dts file. (say GPIOX_18 and GPIOAO_2 for example for amlogic s905x chip)

What should I write in my device-tree?